# Infinite scroll, how do I create a callback for this function?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, callback

Edit: Problem solves. My custom plugin removed an "a" tag, after fixing this it worked like a charm.

Im using infinite scroll on my page with a custom-made plugin where there is a callback function for it. At the moment my callback adress another plugin, and I need to switch to the other function.  The new function that re-fires my script is

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
jQuery(document).removeClass('colorbox');
wprssbind();

});
```

And my current callback is:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function() { 
  if(jQuery.fn.colorbox) {
    jQuery( 'a.colorbox' ).colorbox(
      { 
        iframe:true, 
        width:'80%', 
        height:'80%'
      }
    );
  }
});
```

The callback is placed inside infinite scrolls callback window, the old code works, but the new function doesn't.

Comment: I'm not really sure what the question is here.  Are you asking how to write a callback into a jQuery library, or how you can call `wprssbind()` once `colorbox` has finished doing it's thing?

Comment: Hmm. I guess i asked the question wrong, and on further thoughts, I think it´s enough to call just `wprssbind()` since its gonna overide the other code anyways.

Comment: OK, I'll write that as an answer so others are aware.